# Creating 'select' listboxes using FormHelper in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I have two models, `Category` and `Point`. The associations are defined as:

```
Category hasMany Point
Point belongsTo Category
```

I would like, when adding `Points` to my database, to be able to select the category it belongs to from a `<select>` box, along with the rest of the form data.

Where would I need to `set` the category list and how could I do it? And how would I produce the select box?

I assume it could be done with

```
$form->input('categorieslist',array('type'=>'select')); //categorieslist needs
                                                        //setting somewhere.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the controller:

```
$categories = $this->Point->Category->find('list');
$this->set(compact('categories'));
```

In the view:

```
$form->input('category_id',array('type'=>'select'));
```

Comment: This goes in the points_controller right? I added it there and it pops up a select box in the view but doesn't populate it...

Comment: nevermind i sorted it ... had the first bit in the wrong action :)

Comment: Might be worth updating your question with a bit more of your code, then. What Aziz is suggesting is the right way, assuming your `Point` model `belongsTo` your `Category` model.

Answer (score 7):

Also to generalize a bit:

In a View with access to the Form helper

```
<?php
    echo $form->input( 'dataKey', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'key1' => 'val1',
            'key2' => 'val2',
        ),
    ));
?>
```

The above will render a select input with two options. You can also place an empty option as the first item. Passing a value of true will simply append an empty option with a blank value to the beginning of the options rendered in the HTML.

```
<?php
    echo $form->input( 'dataKey', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'key1' => 'val1',
            'key2' => 'val2',
        ),
        'empty' => true,
    ));
?>
```

You can pass a string to the 'empty' key to have it display custom text as the key field for the empty option.

```
<?php
    echo $form->input( 'dataKey', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'California' => 'CA',
            'Oregon' => 'OR',
        ),
        'empty' => 'choose a state',
    ));
?>
```

One last example, you can also pre-select an option with the selected key. The value should match the *value* of one of the select options, not the key.

```
<?php
    echo $form->input( 'dataKey', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'California' => 'CA',
            'Oregon' => 'OR',
        ),
        'empty' => 'choose a state',
        'selected' => 'California',
    ));
?>
```

---

#### From the Model

`Model->find( 'list', array( ... ));` will always return an array formatted for use with select box options. If you pass data to your view stored in a variable with a lowercase plural model name, that is, `( $this->set( 'categories', $categories );`, then you will automagically generate drop downs for related models by using the form helper in the view and passing it a data index of the same model name in singular form suffixed with "_id".

[Aziz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658432/creating-select-listboxes-using-formhelper-in-cakephp/2658476#2658476) at #2 is the example of that automagic kicking in.

- [CakePHP 1.3 Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements)
- [CakePHP1.2 Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements)